# using url with Putty to access Unix server

Tags: ssh, unix, putty

I need to access UNIX server from my windows machine and will be using PUTTY.  Can I access the UNIX server with the url rather than direct IP address?  I am getting error that host cannot be found and am wondering if there is something special I have to do to use the URL - perhaps quote.  Does anyone know what I need to do differently, if anything to use the URL rather than IP?

Comment: You've got to use either the IP address or a hostname that can be resolved to this IP address.

Comment: What happens if you use `nslookup hostname` in a command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the host name out of the URL and have Putty connect to that host name.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the hostname, but not the full the URL. If it's not working, make sure that your machine is resolving the hostname correctly and can reach the remote server. Try pinging the hostname from the command prompt. The ping program should resolve the hostname for you and give back the IP address. Make sure the IP is correct, and of course, that the pings are successful.

Comment: I could not ping the url - ping could not find host.  I will get hostname.

Comment: You cannot use a URL. A URL is a structured name that refers to data. In PuTTY you have to enter a *hostname* to connect to. A hostname is a part of a URL (eg. `http://google.com/adsense` where `google.com` is the hostname).

Comment: You are correct! Sorry, wrong use of terminology on my part (URL vs hostname). Corrected my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The ping test says nothing as most current Linux systems are pre-configured to ignore the ICMP ECHO (which is what ping uses).

Answer (score 0):

For me `ssh://FQHN` always worked from [KeePass2](https://keepass.info/) and from Windows Explorer (FQHN is the fully-qualified hostname).

See also [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Scheme for Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) and Secure Shell (SSH) (draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04.txt)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04).

Likewise I verified that `ssh://{USER}@{TITLE}` also works as expected in KeePass2 (when I enter the FQHN as "Title" (and the username as "User", obviously)).